# Display answer in UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, function, math, uitextfield

Lets say I have:

```
int a = textbox1;
int b = textbox2;
answer = a + b;
```

How do you get "answer" to display in textbox3? I'm sure this is a very simple question, but believe it or not, I have done a lot of researching and found nothing. If you could please give an example as "Text" and as "numbers with decimals" I would greatly appreciate it!! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should probably start to accept answers to some of your questions if the answer was helpful. It gives you points toward your reputation and it also gives more incentive for others to answer your questions since they also get points if you accept their answers. =)

Comment: Thank you all for your fast replies! On my other questions, I have not accepted the answers because it's not clear to me. I had asked for further explaining for my understanding. Not to mention, their answers I have yet to get to actually work. Plus, I just crossed the reputation to accept answers :) Thank you again. I'm also trying to answer other questions that are easy, as I am new myself and still learning. I have been reading C++ and Objective-C, I knew cout was a call in C++, but was having trouble in objective-C with the formatting. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Anyway you could look at the segmented Controller question? Your answers are easy to understand! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a and b should probably be floats or doubles if you want decimal values.  You can try something like this:

```
double a = [[textBox1 text] doubleValue];
double b = [[textBox2 text] doubleValue];

[textBox3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", (a + b)]];
```

Comment: Format specifier of double is %lf, %f is for float. Though it may not be big deal for simple uses.

Comment: I have `[myTextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f''", ([[PrefLabel text] doubleValue])]];` and it's not displaying the decimal value, only showing the whole number and not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I have another one that's exactly the same and showing correctly...any ideas? So it displaying as `11"` intead of `11.00"`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `text` property of `NSString` to get and set it's text. Use `intValue` method of `NSString` to convert the string to integer (assuming that the string contains a valid integer). And finally use `stringWithFormat` to create a string which contains an integer.

Here is the one line code.

```
textBox3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [textBox1.text intValue] + [textBox2.text intValue]];
```